Is there a tracker of de-facto partitioned countries (due to civil wars)?
I'm curious if there are now more de-facto partitioned countries than at the height of the [previous] Cold War (US-USSR). Of the top of my head: Libya, Sudan, Mali, Yemen, Somalia, Georgia, Moldova etc. qualify. I found https://www.cfr.org/global-conflict-tracker but this isn't too satisfyingly as e.g. it lists Venezuela on par with Yemen, but no non-government faction controls a sizeable portion of Venezuela, AFAICT. And in contrast, it doesn't list Georgia or Moldova even though they are partitioned due a past civil war, because the hostilities are not presently ongoing much there.

When does a partitioned country begin to count as multiple distinct countries for the purpose of this question?

@phoog: when they have enough recognition, e.g. Serbia due to Kosovo is an edge case as IIRC about half the UN countries recognize Kosovo. (Checking now that with google, it's slightly more than half that do.)

How do you define "enough"?  (For that matter, how do you define "partitioned"?)  It just seems like the question is too vague to have an objective answer.

@phoog territorial control by forces that claim to be a government [of sorts]. And whom disagree as to the legitimacy of the others' control. I think the examples are self explanatory, e.g. in Libya multiple governments claim the whole country and each control a part of it. Sudan is similar enough. In Georgia or Moldova various separatist self-declared republics claim [& control] only a part a part of the country's territory, but the UN-recognized government still claims the whole country.

What about e.g. China/Taiwan or the Koreas?

@StuartF: however you'd count them, that situation hasn't changed since the 1950s, so would not matter dynamics-wise. Yes, the DPRK is roughly in the same situation as the DDR was: international recognition but more-or-less not by their neighbor. However those edge case are few compared to all the guerillas that Mao etc. supported in Africa. I'm not too good with that history, e.g. IDK much if those ended up controlling large territories.

@StuartF: interestingly for the DPRK the recognition by is over half the countries, but for the DDR it seems it was under half, according to the maps I can find on Wikipedia.
